# android read FCM data from notificationManager.getActiveNotifications

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I'm using [Capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/) for my App, I have an use case similar to whatsapp, when users receive a new message if your app is in background, you receive FCM notification in the notification tray, later if user open that particular chat directly by opening the app(without clicking on the notification), i'd like to clear that notification from the notification tray.
so here's what I thought

1. get active notification
2. find the active chat notifications by filtering extra data sent by FCM
3. clear those notifications programatically

however android's `notificationManager.getActiveNotifications` doesn't seem to provide access to FCM data.

below is the payload i'm posting to FCM(i want to use chatId and type in data section to clear active notifications).

```
  {
    "android": {
      "priority": "high"
    },
    "notification": {
      "title": "you have a new message from XYZ",
      "body": "hello"
    },
    "data": {
      "messageId": "62971793-0111-4c9b-bbb2-bb78262a0543",
      "chatId": "631e162f5f286c23d13e06d5",
      "type": "CHAT_NEW_MESSAGE"
    },
    "token": "fcmToken"
  }
```

[Here's the capacitor plugins Android Logic](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-plugins/blob/main/push-notifications/android/src/main/java/com/capacitorjs/plugins/pushnotifications/PushNotificationsPlugin.java#L93) to get the delivered/active notification.
how can I achieve above use case?